# how do you check if two keys are pressed consecutively in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a tkinter app that checks if two keys are pressed consecutively. For example, if the user presses ":" and then the enter key right after. Is there a way to do this using key events in tkinter?

I have tried doing the following, but it does not work.

```
if key_pressed == ':':
    if key_pressed == '<Enter>':
        print("ok")
```

Comment: My guess is you would have a stack where you place key presses on-top. If you peek the last one (`":"`) before placing the the next (`"ENTER"`), you can assure that they were pressed consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to save a state for each keypress which stores the last key pressed:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
last_key = None

def keypress_handler(event):
    global last_key
    key_pressed = event.keysym
    print(key_pressed)
    if key_pressed == 'b':
        if last_key == 'a':
            print('Pressed first "a" and then "b"')
    last_key = key_pressed

root.bind('<KeyPress>', keypress_handler)

root.mainloop()
```

If you are going to use modifiers like shift, ctrl or alt you'll have to filter them out because they also generate keypress events.